# Angular 6 - Importing shared module for child modules

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

I'm trying to make a shared module, but it's don't want to work somehow.

The shared module looks like this:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedMetaModule } from './shared-meta';
import { ApplicationState } from './state/application-state';
import { MilitaryTimePipe } from './pipes/military-time-pipe';
import { KeysPipe } from './pipes/object-pipe';
import { GirlsClass } from './advertisers/girls';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [
        KeysPipe,
        MilitaryTimePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        SharedMetaModule,
        KeysPipe,
        MilitaryTimePipe
    ],
    providers: [ApplicationState]
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return { ngModule: SharedModule };
    }
}
```

I have an app.module.ts like this:

```
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
```

Then I have a profile-gallery.module.ts where a pipe from the shared module would be used.

If I don't import the shared module in the profile-gallery module I got this error:

`The pipe 'keys' could not be found.`

If I import the shared module to the profile-gallery module I got this error:

`MetaModule already loaded; import in root module only.`

How could work the shared module in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of a Shared module is to import it in all the required modules, more than once. So there is no need for the *forRoot* method that makes sure it's imported only once.

Remove the *forRoot* method entirely and import the module where needed:

```
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        SharedModule,
```

Comment: Thanks! If i delete the forRoot method from the app.module imports i still have this error:
`Uncaught (in promise): Error: MetaModule already loaded; import in root module only.`
If i delete the shared module from the app.module, i have errors because the pipe (i'm actually refactoring the app to modules with lazy loading)
If i delete the SharedMetaModule from the SharedModule, then i have to import it individually in every module. I dont know what would be the best option :(

Comment: You might have a naming error between SharedMetaModule <-> MetaModule

Comment: The SharedModule's imports the MetaModule: `imports: [
  MetaModule.forRoot({
   provide: MetaLoader,
   useFactory: metaFactory,
   deps: []
  })
 ]`

Comment: At the end i separed out the MetaModule from the SharedModule, and imported the MetaModule in the app.module, then now it looks fine.